# Problem on dword ptr[...] with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assembly

I'm trying to compile a program which worked with the compiler of Visual C++ 6.0. 
Now, I'm compiling it using the compiler of Visual Studio 2010. It compiles but my program crashes on assignment of a variable:

```
sapHigh = ctx->saphigh;
```

In assembler code (using Visual Studio Debugger), this instruction is decomposed by:

```
00410DF3  mov         eax,dword ptr [ctx]  
00410DF6  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+20h]  
00410DF9  mov         dword ptr [sapHigh],ecx
```

The instruction "mov eax, dword ptr[ctx]" return 0x00000000 in eax and the program crashes. But the debugger can see the real value of ctx pointer which is "0x0172287a". If I change the value of the eax register with its real value, "0x0172287a", the program still working fine until the next assignment.

Does anybody know why this instruction doesn't work ? Is this a problem with compilation options ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your program use any external libraries or dlls which were compiled to work with the old application? We had some problems like this when using stl strings between dlls compiled with VC6 and visual studio 2003 I remember.

Comment: Have you tried to make a breakpoint on `ctx` location?

Comment: Can you post the source of the program? It's kind of hard to guess from these snippets...

Comment: @NotJarvis Normally, all external libraries and dlls are compiled with the new compiler.

Comment: @RedX Unfortunately, I can't post the source of the program, sorry...

Comment: Not enough information. For one you don't give the error with which it crashes. Furthermore it's highly unlikely that you have found a CPU bug with this. It'd be interesting which of the three instructions ultimately causes the crash. Oh and it's not clear where `sapHigh` comes from. If this is a stack value and you smashed your stack some way, you have yet another possibility for a cause. At least if `ctx` is a valid pointer and the offset of `saphigh` inside the struct is still inside valid memory you wouldn't encounter any issues. I strongly suggest using a profiler like VTune or AQTime ...

Comment: Basically your claim is contradictory. `ctx` cannot at the same time be valid and invalid. However, it's well possible that the DWORD to which `ctx` points is NULL. And that would explain it as well.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (I'm a coworker of Cedekasme) what happens is, you look up the value of `ctx` in the debugger you see a valid value (aka `0x0172287a`), but you step over the `mov eax, dword ptr [ctx]`, and look at `eax`: it's value is `0`. if you step one more time it crashes, if before stepping you manually set the value of eax to `0x0172287a` it works...

Comment: @f4 let me try again. `0x0172287a` is the value of `[ctx]` or of `ctx`? I.e. is that the address of the supposed struct/class or is it the variable holding that address? It's a fine but important difference. Also, you say "it works". What works? Do you mean it does not crash or do you mean that the output is exactly what it would be expected to be (i.e. have you inspected the memory location to verify it contains what it should). A dump of all segment and general purpose registers (eip, esp, ebp, e*x) *before* each of the opcodes might be useful.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED obviously we're talking about the value of ctx in the debugger so [ctx] in assembly... and when I say it works, I mean the next instruction (00410DF6) yields the correct value

Comment: @f4: fair enough. So you are implying more or less that the CPU does the wrong thing on an instruction that is commonly used. Without more information from your side, including register dumps and whether this code is single-threaded etc, no one will be able to help you without just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

That's a long gap of 10-12 years. I recommend you compile the program in VC10 with ALL compiler warnings enabled, and attempt to remove all of them. It includes all warnings related to deprecated stuff, 64-bit warnings, performance warnings, and C++ compliant warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the memory for the variable `ctx` is not longer valid. If `ctx` is for example part of some dynamically allocated struct that got freed earlier, or if it's a reference or pointer to an out-of-scope stack variable, all kinds of undefined behaviors can happen.

Using invalid memory might not crash if (by chance) no other functions overwrote that memory, but using a different compiler and a different runtime library can easily lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try `lea eax, dword ptr[ctx]` ?

Also I've seen problems like that happen if the pointer to the array is passed to a function. When the array is defined within a function everything's fine.